# What is an "active" uniform block in OpenGL

Tags: android, ios, opengl-es, webgl2

The [OpenGL documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetActiveUniformBlock.xhtml) is not very clear about what is an **active** uniform block (versus those are not active). So my understanding is it is about them being referenced/used in a shader program... or is it!

Consider the following shader program:

**Vertex Shader**

```
#version 300 es
precision highp float;

layout(std140) uniform globals
{
    mat4 world_view_proj;
};

layout(std140) uniform foo
{
    vec3 bar;
};

layout(std140) uniform dog
{
    vec3 cat;
};

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position0;
layout(location = 4) in lowp vec4 color0;
out lowp vec4 v_color;

void main ( )
{
    v_color = color0;
    gl_Position = position0 * world_view_proj;
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
#version 300 es
precision highp float;

in lowp vec4 v_color;
layout(location = 0) out lowp vec4 frag_color;

void main()
{
    frag_color = v_color;
}
```

---

Even though I don't use `foo` or `dog` uniform blocks, a query to get the number of active uniform blocks...

```
GLint count = 0;
glGetProgramiv(program, GL_ACTIVE_UNIFORM_BLOCKS, &count);
for (auto i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    ...
}
```

...always returns **3** for this shader program. I get the same result whether I run on Android, iOS or WebGL2. I haven't tested on *desktop* OpenGL (versus OpenGL ES 3.0) but I don't expect a different result (but I guess it could?).

1. So what does it means for a uniform block to be **active** then?
2. And is there a way to only retrieve *used* uniform blocks (skip unused ones)?

Thanks!

Comment: if you're using webgl2 you should **not** be referencing the OpenGL docs. You should be referencing the [OpenGL ES spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.0/es_spec_3.0.pdf) or [reference pages](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/). Note that the reference pages are not guaranteed to be correct so always refer to the spec when in doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A uniform block that is not in use may be optimized out by the implementation. But it *may not* as well; that's all up to the implementation. OpenGL does not *require* implementations to optimize out unused uniforms or blocks; it simply allows for the possibility.

There is no way to guaranteeably fetch which uniform blocks are in use.

Comment: Is there any reference anywhere that state this is not required by the implementation?

Comment: @Deathicon: There is nothing in the specification that states that it *is* required. Therefore, it is not required. The closest you get in the specification is "The set of active resources for any interface is implementation-dependent because it depends on various analysis and optimizations performed by the compiler and linker."